# Exporting multiple Dataframes to multiple CSV files - Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv, dataframe

I have this dict of dataframes and I would like to export all df to multiple csv files:

```
print(final)

    'Prod':                         Timestamp   Flag         group
 0     2019-10-21  07:39:28.052763  begin  Prod
 1     2019-10-21  07:39:58.332252    end  Prod
 2     2019-10-21  07:40:00.279654  begin  Prod
 3     2019-10-21  07:41:58.631835    end  Prod
 4     2019-10-21  07:42:54.243338  begin  Prod


 [5354 rows x 3 columns],
 'Clean':                         Timestamp   Flag     group
 0     2019-10-21  07:48:26.740378  begin  Clean
 1     2019-10-21  07:48:28.272688    end  Clean
 2     2019-10-21  07:48:37.306045  begin  Clean
 3     2019-10-21  07:48:41.689466    end  Clean
 4     2019-10-21  08:32:46.240015  begin  Clean
```

So I tried this, but it doesn't work, I think the problem is in the line "filename =..."

```
for key in final.keys():
    filename = [key]+"/*.csv"
    final[key].to_csv(filename, sep = ',' , encoding = 'utf-8', index = False)
```

I need this for datascience purpose. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try: `filename = key + ".csv"` or `filename = f'{key}.csv'` when using python 3.6+

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: @luigigi error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Prod.csv'

Comment: @ThonyNadhir remove the `/`. I edited my comment

Comment: @rpanai yeah : can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: @luigigi it works ! thanks

Comment: @luigigi can you answer the question please ? not with a comment.
Because it's ok for me ;) ! thanks a lot